# AngularJS Directive Numeric Format Masking

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, masking, angularjs-filter

The directive I have created uses the function setFormatting to mask the text value in an input field.

```
scope.$watch(element, function() {
    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(setFormatting(element.val(), attrs.symbol));
    modelCtrl.$render();
});

element.bind('blur', function() {
    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(setFormatting(element.val(), attrs.symbol));
    modelCtrl.$render();
});
```

The scope.$watch applies the mask when the content is loaded/applied the first time, the element.bind applies the mask for the other times.  The scope.$watch is storing the symbol (if there is one) as part of the ng-model variable.  The element.bind is not.  I thought $setViewValue() and $render() did not update the ng-model variable.  Where is the variable being updated?

See attached fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PJ3M4/

Thanks.

Comment: in easy words do you want to add commas and `°` during typing into input field?

Comment: Yes, only in the input field.  But this directive is being used for various symbols, not just the ° symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the ng-model to store values the way I wanted to by adding a modelCtrl.$parsers.push() { ... } to my scope.$watch() { ... }.

```
scope.$watch(element, function() {
    modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
        showAlert("Watch", 1);

        if (!prev) {
            prev = false;
            var returnVal = checkVal(inputValue, modelCtrl, decimals, true, minVal, maxVal);

            if (String(returnVal) === ".") {
                setAndRender(modelCtrl, "");
                return "";
            }
            else {
                return returnVal;
            }
        }
        return String(inputValue).replace(/[^0-9 . -]/g, '');
    });

    prev = true;
    setAndRender(modelCtrl, setFormatting(element.val(), decimals, attrs.prefix, attrs.symbol));
});
```

Answer (score 16):

Here we used `$formatters.unshift` and `$filter`:

[image]

**JS**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);

fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = 123456879;
});
fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope'];

fessmodule.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

            var symbol = "°"; // dummy usage

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue) +  symbol;
            });

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber) + symbol);
                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="test" format="number"/>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/804/)**</kbd>

*As a side note*

You can find this helpful too: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/805/)

Comment: C!pher, Maxim's answer is very well done and the declarative method of using directives is a great approach, I would recommend selecting his answer.  All the best.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim. Exactly what I want. In case you get some time can you please help with some explanation of the code it will help newbie like me :). Thanks again.

Comment: Hi maxim, I really like your answer but I have one concern. When I try to edit the input number the cursor goes back to the last number.

Answer (score 1):

The `$watch` is executed inside a 'digest' loop. The `element.bind` callback is called from outside angular, so you must add an explicit call to `scope.$apply()`:

```
element.bind('blur', function() {
    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(setFormatting(element.val(), attrs.symbol));
    modelCtrl.$render();
    scope.$apply();
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdCmV/1/)

See the docs for info about [AngularJS's event loop](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#what-are-scopes_integration-with-the-browser-event-loop).

Comment: I wanted to store the value of the number into the variable, not the mask value.

Comment: Then you should use a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) to display de value. The `$watch` function is following the digest loop while your element.bind call is breaking the data-binding.

Comment: See @MaximShoustin answer for a filter example.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use simply

```
ui-mask="{{'999,999,999°'}}"
```

Comment: ui-mask is third party directive. It is not angular native.

Comment: At least, provide the 3rd party directive website.