# Formatting input values, but having difficilties with updating the model

Tags: angularjs, number-formatting, angular-directive

I'm trying to solve an issue with formatting some input fields.

When I enter the value I want the model to updated as I type, like this:
I enter ex '1200000', i want it to display in the input field '1.200.000' and the model should update as 1200000.

I also want the field to pre-formatted if the model already has a value.
Likewise I need to format in percentage, please [see my example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XETIM2KuC0zHfcNUt03k):

```
  <div ng-controller="testController as testCtrl">

 {{ 'Model: ' + testCtrl.value1 }} 
 <input type="text" cr-numeric ng-model="testCtrl.value1" /> <br />

{{ 'Model: ' + testCtrl.value2 }} 
<input type="text" cr-numeric="interest_3_decimals" ng-model="testCtrl.value2" />
```

The formatting work fine when I'm entering the values, but I can't make it to work when the model already has a value and to update to value accordingly when i'm entering data.

Please anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

If You need format only in view, You can use [number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) filter;

Just:

```
Model: {{ testCtrl.value1 | number:2 }}
```

So, in model You still have original value;

Comment: I only want the input fields to formatted and if the there is a model connected to it - I can't change the values.

Comment: @UffePetersen You can use some pluggins: [angular-input-masks](http://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/), [stackoverflow example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861408/angularjs-directive-numeric-format-masking);